# SQLite Transactions and LastInsertRowID

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, transactions, system.data.sqlite

I use SQLite databases with with System.Data.Sqlite implementation for .NET.

I insert records in a loop into multiple tables (example is given with two tables). I first start a transaction, then insert one record into table 1. I then take `connection.LastInsertRowID` and insert a record together with this value (as a foreign key) into table 2.

I do this for all my records and then commit the transaction.

Why does this work and does it hinder performance? How can the `LastInsertRowID` value be known if the records have not really been entered due to the transaction not being commited yet? Does the value need to be guessed every time from the previous steps and thus lower the performance?

Comment: Can't verify right now, but I suspect it'll pick the next number and just drop the number (ie leave a hole in the sequence) it if the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: Is this bad? What if records are deleted in the same transaction before the inserts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From inside your own database connection, all changes you've made in the transaction are already visible.
(They would vanish only if you were to roll back the transaction.)

The changes you make are actually written into the table in the page cache.
If the page cache overflows, the changes are written to the database file (but with a backup of the old data so that the transaction can be rolled back).
See [Atomic Commit In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) for details.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your answer. Interesting stuff :-)